# Remember original URL before login so that user can be redirected back to that URL

Tags: jsf, url, session, authentication

I want to store the first URL the user hit my application on so that I might redirect them back to that URL after succesful log-in.
The unlogged in user is directed to a login page by a filter I believe.

I have a session scoped bean I intend to store the URL (including queryString paramaters) to which I have no problem using from my log-in bean. The problem I have is storing that URL (as a String) in the first place.

How might I do that?

one attempt I have made in my template is :

```
<f:attribute name="originalURL" value="#{request.requestURI}?#{request.queryString}" />
    <f:metadata>  
        <f:event rendered="#{not sessionData.authenticated}" type="preRenderView" listener="#{sessionData.recordOriginalURL(originalURL)}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

However in debug this does not result in the `recordOriginalURL` method being called

Comment: Answer depends on who's redirecting/forwarding the user to the login page and how that's done.

Comment: A (session)filter using response.sendRedirect - Im now thinking I should be storing the URL in the sessionFilter

Comment: Look like you got it now.